# referencing multiple tables through a single column in sql

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

In SQL can a single column in a table reference multiple tables?

E.g. if we have tables `employee` (PK `emp_id, name`) and `customer` (PK `cust_id, name`)

Can we have a table `contact` (id references `[employee, customer], number`);

Or do we necessarily need to make 2 tables:

`contact_cust` (`cust_id` references `customer, number`) and `contact_emp` (`emp_id` references `employee, number`)

I know that the second choice would be better even if the first one were possible. I just want to know is the first way possible?

Comment: *In SQL can a single column in a table reference multiple tables* - no this is **not** possible. A foreign key always references **one target table** (and **one table only**).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can't. One option is to first generalise Employee/Customer as "Party" or "Stakeholder".
I.e.

```
TABLE: Party(PK Party_Id,
             Name)  
TABLE: Employeee(PK Emp_Id REFERENCES Party.Party_Id, 
                 Salary)  
TABLE: Customer(PK Cust_Id REFERENCES Party.Party_Id,
                CreditRating)
```

Then Contact would reference Party.

Comment: I wonder why SQL do not allow to have single reference to multiple tables. I'm not a SQL guru, but as far I know reference is simply integer. Let's say I would like to have reference to two different tables. In order to avoid ID conflicts first could have only ids from 1 to 2^31 and second from 2^31+1 to 2^32. No conflicts and you can say from ID which table to fetch.

Comment: Love this solution compared to others that I've seen elsewhere.  Requires a bit of overhead but it's so much cleaner than doing complex comparisons.

Comment: given a `Party_Id` how to find its type?

Comment: @mhrsalehi depends. if a party can't be employeee and customer at the same time you can add a type column.
if a party can be both types at the same time you can either add 2 bit columns to party indicating whether it's or not employeee and whether it's or not customer. you'll need to check that at least one of those is true while inserting/updating or it won't make sense.
Or you can not add those columns and check if the value exists on the employeee and customer tables

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot have a single column with a foreign key that references two different tables.